# Running small scripts upon data entry in a table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I did not find this information anywhere in the snowflake documentation so I decided to ask here.
My usecase requires me to run a small script when there is a new data entry in a snowflake table. I know that snowflake supports SQL tasks but my requirement is a bit more mathematical and I would need a proper script to be able to solve it. I am flexible on the language for the script but I wanted to know if there is a continuous integration for this workflow.

I know the alternate solution of running an on-demand instance hosted on some cloud platform but I wanted to know if something like this is possible within the Snowflake hosted warehouse.

Would appreciate any responses. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you importing the data? Why would tasks and streams not work in this case?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I think I was just lost in the documentation. Francesco's answer tells me the procedure using the same idea and that makes it clear. Tasks and Streams would solve this for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal using Steams and Tasks:

1. create a Stream on your Table (with APPEND_ONLY = TRUE possibly, as you need to search for new entries only);
2. create a [Stored Procedure](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html) (as of today you'll need to write it in Javascript) that consumes the Stream and does the computation you need;
3. create a Task scheduled to runs every 1 minute and only if the stream is not empty ([SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('<stream_name>')](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html)) which will run the Stored Procedure at (2)

Comment: That would solve my usecase. The limitation of JS only is annoying but I think I can at least get started based on this. Thanks a lot!